# Not only... but also

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I would like others to tell me if this sentence is correct. I don't know if I should use *we* before *met*.

> We not only studied but also met, laughed and became friends.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is grammatically correct but it is more understandable if you put a *we* before *also*:

> We not only studied but **we** also met, laughed and became friends.

Comment: I agree with you, although I think we could omit the extra _we_ if the verbs were different (and more related). For example: _We not only dined but also danced. He not only mourned but also wept._ When the verbs are not so related, though, it often reads better with the extra pronoun, as you suggest: _We not only ate lunch but we also fixed the car._

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is grammatical. You'd most likely need another 'we' with another the word order used for emphasis:

> Not only did we study (together) but we also met, laughed and became
>   friends.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/word-order-and-focus/not-only-but-also